# Calling specific columns of attribute table using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, attribute-table

I'm trying to figure out how to spline specific columns of a shapefile attribute table, but my question is intermediate to this.

How do I select a range of columns, e.g. the 20th column to the right-most column, as fields to apply a for loop operation to?

My first thought was to try numpy, but I'm open to ideas. For now I'd just like to either print the names of the desired columns or specify the columns to be iterated in the for loop line.

```
import arcpy, numpy as np
from arcpy.sa import *

fieldList = arcpy.ListFields(r"C:\Users\afullhar\Desktop\Lab6\Data For Lab on habitat modeling\Layers\start_data\10_km_Points.shp")

for field in fieldList:
    print format(field.name[19,:])
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

that's nearly it, but the referencing of the field should be done on the field list, not the field name

```
fieldList = arcpy.ListFields(r"C:\your.shp")

for field in fieldList[19:]:
    print field.name
```