# Selecting columns in from an attribute table in ArcPy using a list (rather than slices or indices)?

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, attribute-table, arcgis-pro, list

I have seen [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/140653/calling-specific-columns-of-attribute-table-using-arcpy) to [Calling specific columns of attribute table using ArcPy?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/140653/115), but it uses a slice to select columns.

I would like to select them using a list.

Example code that doesn't work:

```
import arcpy    
select_cols = ['FID', 'Shape', 'OBJECTID'] # the list of columns
    for field in field_list[select_cols]:
        print(field.name)
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "", line 1, in 
>       TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list

A different attempt

```
field_list2 = field_list[select_cols]
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "", line 1, in 
>       TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list

Comment: On a related note, I found this, which is sort of what I want, but by deleting. https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/236779/removing-multiple-fields-in-arcpy-with-remove-function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you need the field objects (and not just the field names)...

You could use a list comprehension.  For example:

```
for field in [f for f in field_list if f.name in select_cols]:
    print field.name
```

Or without a list comprehension, it could be done like:

```
for field in field_list:
    if field.name not in select_cols:
        continue
    print field.name
```